# setting tag value for button to unhide on a cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tags

I have button on tableview cell which is added programatically and I added this button on every cell using for loop also I have set it "alpha value =0". What i want is that when I click on particular cell it should show me the button on that cell only.

Here what i did :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

        if(tableView == self.todayTableView)
    {
 for (int i = 0; i < first.count; i++)
        {
      record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            [record1 setAlpha:0];
            record1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 23, 25, 25);

            [record1 addTarget:self action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [record1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone-g-ico.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

[cell addSubview:record1];

}
 [record1 setTag:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == _todayTableView)
    {

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {

                if( record1.tag == 8)
                {
                    [record1 setAlpha:1];

                }

            }
    }
}
```

when I click on cell it showing button on a last cell only.

plz suggest??

Comment: do you to add a single button on every cell or multiple buttons

Comment: @VinodKumar same button on a every cell.when I click on particular cell I want the button on that cell only ,others should be hidden

Comment: you can use model class because cell reuse when you scrolling the tableview it showing on different cells@iOSBeginner

Comment: @VinodKumar model class ?? sorry maybe its silly question  but I am totally new in iOS .

Comment: i will provide you whole code for this in my answer@iOSBeginner

Comment: download sample from my answer@iOSBeginner

Comment: please let me know if you facing any problem@iOSBeginner

Answer (score 1):

change this ===>

```
if(tableView == self.todayTableView)
    {
 for (int i = 0; i < first.count; i++)
        {
      record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            [record1 setAlpha:0];
            record1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 23, 25, 25);

            [record1 addTarget:self action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:record1];

}
```

to ==>

```
  if(tableView == self.todayTableView)
    {
 for (__strong UIView *view in Cell.contentView.subviews) {
       if(view.tag==101){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;}
    }
      record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
record1.tag=101;
            [record1 setAlpha:0];
            record1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 23, 25, 25);

            [record1 addTarget:self action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [record1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone-g-ico.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

[Cell.contentView addSubview:record1];

}
```

/********replace didSelect********************/

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == _todayTableView)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]; 

      for (__strong UIView *view in Cell.contentView.subviews) {
           if(view.tag==101){
           view.alpha=1;
           break;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: property lastIndexPath not found on "NSIndexPath "

Comment: sorry, replace that with indexPath

Comment: please tell the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reload tableview or reload cell. You can try this code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // change Alpha button
    if(tableView == _todayTableView) {
        [cell.record1 setAlpha:0];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use for loop to add button, cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is called everytime a new row is added.

please try something like in the below code :

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
if(tableView == self.todayTableView)
{
        UIButton *record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [record1 setAlpha:0];
        record1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 23, 25, 25);

        [record1 addTarget:self action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [record1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone-g-ico.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

    [record1 setTag:indexPath.row];

}
    return cell;
```

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
YourCellClass *cell = (YourCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *record1 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:8];

if(tableView == _todayTableView)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if( record1 != nil)
        {
            [record1 setAlpha:1];

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for the for loop suggestion :) it is showing on the every cell but it is showing somewhat blurred image when i didn't use for loop.

Comment: i am not using custom cell for this .

Comment: Change the icon image of the button, use image with better resolution. And if you are not using custom cell then you can simply use UITableViewCell class to create object of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are storing the `record1` Button in a @property variable of your class. Do not do that, because for every cell that will be created, that new button will be saved to the same @property over and over again. So in the end, only the last created UIButton actually is available to you, because all the previously created ones got written over.

Here is a solution to your problem:

1.) In the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}` function you should create a local variable for `record1`-Button, like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(tableView == self.todayTableView) {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.count; i++) {
            // create NEW button, don't store it in a @property reference
            UIButton* record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            // now continue as you did
}
```

2.) It is important that **only one** UI-Element in your UITableViewCell gets the tag of the indexPath.row property. Because then you can access the UI-Element (in your case the Button) by its tag property:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get the UITableViewCell
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get the button and set its alpha property
    UIButton* record1 = (UIButton*) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    record1.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

And one more hint: The first cell will have the indexPath.row as a "0" value. That will cause problems probably too, since every UIView-Element in your cell will have a tag=0 by default. So it is probably better to assign tags like indexPath.row + 100 for example.

Comment: thanks for the answer !!! as you are saying that need to create local variable for button ,I did that initially but then i can't access that outside the CellForRowAtIndexPath...so I declared that globally as UIButton *record1;

Answer (score 0):

**Try Once**

```
1.Create a mutable Array globally as 
@interface YourClassName ()
{
    NSMutableArray*selectedCellArr;
}

2.In ViewDidLoad Allocate Memory to that array as selectedCellArr = [NSMutableArray new];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    if(tableView == self.todayTableView)
    {

       UIButton*record1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
       [record1 setAlpha:0];
       record1.frame = CGRectMake(250, 23, 25, 25);
       [record1 addTarget:self action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [record1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"microphone-g-ico.png"] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
       [record1 setTag:indexPath.row];
       [cell addSubview:record1];

    if ([selectedCellArr containsObject:indexPath]) [record1 setAlpha:1];

       return cell;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == _todayTableView)
    {
       if ([selectedCellArr containsObject:indexPath]) {
             [selectedCellArr removeObject: indexPath];
       }else{
             [selectedCellArr addObject: indexPath];
       }
   }
}
```